# Informative Censoring and joint modelling

Tags: survival, panel-data

I am trying to understand the benefits of joint models for longitudinal and survival data. 
As far as I understand it the primary intention is to make the survival analysis more precise by allowing measurement errors in the longitudinal process.
My primary focus, however, is the longitudinal process.
If I am interested in the effect of a covariate on the longitudinal process, will the estimate be biased if I do not account for informative censoring? If so, how does a joint model help in this situation?